# Como implementar corretamente um System.Threading.Monitor em .net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Tenho um trecho de código que implementa um [Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor?view=netframework-4.5.2). O objetivo deste código é não permitir que outra thread escreva no log, enquanto uma delas estiver rodando.

Este código funciona perfeitamente em .net framework 4.5, porém não obtenho o mesmo resultado em .net core.

Aqui a classe que implementa o Monitor:

```
public class Locker
{
    private static bool _entered = false;
    private static readonly object _lock = new object();

    public void LockOn(TimeSpan timeOut, Action method)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Monitor.TryEnter(_lock, timeOut))
                throw new TimeoutException("Não foi possível adquirir lock no tempo especificado");

            _entered = true;
            method();

        }
        finally
        {
            if (_entered)
            {
                Monitor.Exit(_lock);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Aqui o uso dela:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const int ITERATIONS = 5;
    Locker locker = new Locker();
    StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();

    Parallel.ForEach(new string[] { "A", "B" }, (string taskName) =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i)
        {
            locker.LockOn(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), () =>
            {
                //nosso amigo "A" faz sleep de 50ms, enquanto o "B" faz sleep de 100ms
                TimeSpan sleepTime = taskName == "A" ? TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50) : TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
                Task.Delay(sleepTime).Wait();

                log.Append(taskName);
            });
        }
    });

    string finalLog = log.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(finalLog);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Rodando em .net framework eu obtenho o seguinte resultado:

```
ABABABABAB
```

Porém em .net core não consigo ter este mesmo resultado...
O que pode estar errado? Já tentei rodar do .net core 2.0, 2.1 e 3.1.